# How to distinguish between primordial versus kinematic anistropies of CMB

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

The CMB temperature anisotropy, at each order (monopole, dipole, quadrupole etc) in the multipole expansion, is contributed by two effects: (i) partly by the motion of the earth w.r.t the CMB-the *kinematic* anisotropy and (ii) partly was (probably) caused by inflationary perturbations -the *primordial* anisotropy. Is it possible to distinguish and therefore, subtract the kinematic anisotropies from the net anisotropy to obtain the primordial anisotropies?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by, "*at each order in the multipole expansion*"? The Doppler shift anisotropy is always removed first, do you mean different kinematic anisotropies from the one caused by the Earth moving toward the Great Attractor?

Comment: There are anisotropies due to the motion of earth w.r.t the CMB i.e., the effect of boost. I had asked a related question [Finding the CMB temperature anisotropies contributed at different orders due to a uniform boost](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414310/finding-the-cmb-temperature-anisotropies-contributed-at-different-orders-due-to) .I have just started to learn about CMB.

Comment: Got it, higher order spherical harmonics. I've been wondering as well of how the Doppler shift is subtracted. Thanks! (Also fixed what seemed to be a spelling error there. Hopefully this is what you meant. Otherwise please reject the edits.)

Answer (score 1):

The kinematic anisotropy is manifested solely in the dipole anisotropy; specifically, the $Y_{10}$ harmonic if the Earth's motion is taken along the z-axis.